# ¿Cómo cambiar variable de eje x en un gráfico base?

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente tabla de frecuencias en un data frame:

```
i       palabras  f.a.        f.r.    f.a.a.    f.r.a 
1           3       1    0.02083333      1   0.02083333
2           4       1    0.02083333      2   0.04166667
3           5       1    0.02083333      3   0.06250000
4           7       2    0.04166667      5   0.10416667
5           9       3    0.06250000      8   0.16666667
6          10       4    0.08333333     12   0.25000000
7          11       7    0.14583333     19   0.39583333
8          12      10    0.20833333     29   0.60416667
9          13      14    0.29166667     43   0.89583333
10         14       3    0.06250000     46   0.95833333
11         15       2    0.04166667     48   1.00000000
```

y quiero mostrar en una gráfica el polígono de frecuencias de la f.a. y la f.a.a.
He utilizado el siguiente código:

```
plot(TF$f.a.a., type="b", col="brown2",xlab="", ylab="", main="Polígono de frecuencias", yaxt="n", lwd =2)
legend(49, legend=c("f.a.", "f.a.a."), col=c("blue", "brown2"), lwd=2, lty=1, cex=0.8)
axis(2, at = c(10,20,30,40,50,60), cex.axis=1, tck=1, col.ticks="gray")
lines(TF$f.a., pch=18, col="blue", type="b", lty=1, lwd =2)
```

obteniendo el siguiente gráfico:
[image: Polígono de frecuencias del script]
El problema es que el eje x representa el índice correspondiente a cada punto y yo **quiero que muestre la columna palabras** y los datos en función de dicha columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, que `plot()` no dibuje los puntos del eje x con `xact="n"` así finalmente podemos configurarlo tal como queremos: `axis(1, at=TF$i, labels=TF$palabras)`

Finalmente el código:

```
plot(TF$f.a.a., type="b", col="brown2",xlab="", ylab="", main="Polígono de frecuencias", yaxt="n", lwd =2, xaxt="n")
legend(49, legend=c("f.a.", "f.a.a."), col=c("blue", "brown2"), lwd=2, lty=1, cex=0.8)
axis(2, at = c(10,20,30,40,50,60), cex.axis=1, tck=1, col.ticks="gray")
axis(1, at=TF$i, labels=TF$palabras)
lines(TF$f.a., pch=18, col="blue", type="b", lty=1, lwd =2)
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]